# php HTML timetable

Tags: php, html

My first post on SO. I am working on a php based timetable module. It seems 90% of my code is working fine. Just not able to display the loop properly for showing my data in timetable format.

I want my time table to be like this table:

[Required Timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0kbr.png)

My Code:

```
//Array for days starting from 1 for monday
$days = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');

//Selecting all the hours from lectures
$hours = select id, start_time from lectures;

$timetable = select timetable.id, timetable.day, timetable.lecture_id, timetable.subject_id from timetable;

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            //echo "<td>";
            //  echo "Day";
            //echo "</td>";
    foreach($hours as $hh)
                        {
                        echo "<td>";
                        {echo $hh->start_time;}
                        echo "</td>";   
                        }
    echo "</tr>";                   
    foreach($hours as $hour)
        {
            foreach($days as $day)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        foreach($timetable as $tt)
                        {
                            echo "<td>";
                            if ($tt->day==$day AND $tt->lecture_id==$hour->id)
                            {echo $tt->subject_id;}
                            echo "</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";   
                }
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

My output is as below. This is okay except I am unable to put Days in the start of the row. Can anybody help me with this small issue. I think I am messing up with HTML

[Current Timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqNPp.png)

Comment: where you are echoing day ??

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: i think my html is messed up here not getting the right table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it after some googling

```
$days = array("1"=>"Monday", "2"=>"Tuesday", "3"=>"Wednesday", "4"=>"Thursday", "5"=>"Friday", "6"=>"Saturday", "7"=>"Sunday", );

$hours = DB::table('timetablelectures')->select('timetablelectures.id', 'timetablelectures.start_time')
                                ->get();
$timetable = DB::table('timetable')->select('timetable.id', 'timetable.day', 'timetable.lecture_id', 'timetable.subject_id')
                                ->get();
//SET UP SCHEDULE    
$schedule = array();

    foreach($timetable as $tt) 
        {
        foreach($days as $x => $x_value) 
            {
                if ( $tt->day==$x)
                            {
                            $schedule["{$x}"][$tt->lecture_id][] = $tt->subject_id;
                            }
            }
        }


// DISPLAY SCHEDULE, headers first
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td align="center">Time</td>
 <?php foreach ( $hours as $hour ) 
                {
                    echo "<td>  $hour->start_time </td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

foreach ( $days as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "<tr><td>$x_value</td>";

    // roll through days
    foreach ( $hours as $hour ) {
        echo '<td>';
        // check for subjects in this slot
        if ( isset($schedule[$x][$hour->id]) ) {
            // and display each
            foreach ( $schedule[$x][$hour->id] as $subject ) {
                echo "$subject<br>";
            }
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an empty cell in your first row that was showing start times, and then for every row with the subjects, add a cell that shows the day of the week.

Also, I feel you might reduce your triple for-loop to at least a double for-loop if you use an ORDER BY clause in your SQL. Maybe order by day, and then by start time (for the start time, you'll need a join with the lectures table). It also seems that the outer loop should iterate through days, and the inner loop - through start times.

EDIT: You can even just have one loop, if you were to cross join distinct days and start times, order that by days and then start times, and then do a left outer join with your actual timetable. You will end up having NULLs in every row that correspond to a day and time that does not have a scheduled lecture. You will also know that your query gives the same number of rows for every day. With that, you can just create a new `<tr />` every N rows, where N is the number of start times in a day.

EDIT2: Regarding the loop nesting, I meant something like this:
`

```
foreach($days as $day)
    {
        echo "<tr>"; // Every day is a table row
        echo "<td>" . getDayNameByNumber($day) . "</td>" // use one of the methods being suggested here, i.e. indexing into an array of names, a built-in function if PHP has it (would be better, because it would likely follow the system's locale and translate it for you...)
        foreach($hours as $hour)
            {
                    // Every hour in a day is a cell in the row
                    // optimize this loop...
                    foreach($timetable as $tt)
                    {
                        echo "<td>";
                        if ($tt->day==$day AND $tt->lecture_id==$hour->id)
                        {echo $tt->subject_id;}
                        echo "</td>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";   
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I am unable to do. How to get an empty cell echoing day of the week

Comment: Firstly, declare an array with names of the days, e.g. `$daysOfWeek = array("Monday", "Tuesday", ...., "Sunday")`. Then, after `echo "<tr>";` right outside your innermost loop, do `echo "<td>$daysOfWeek[$day]</td>";`. You can probably use that new array instead of $days, as well - use  `foreach($daysOfWeek as $dayIndex => $dayName)`

Comment: I might need to take the last idea back - I am not sure if PHP guarantees that iteration to be ordered by key, strictly speaking. In practice, it probably should be...

Comment: I think you should also make sure that you iterate by days in your outer loop, and by start times in your inner loop, and not the other way around as the code is currently doing, because every row corresponds to a day, and every cell in a row - to a start time

Comment: An edit for my first comment above - I meant `$daysOfWeek[$day - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're calling the right MySQL table fields.

If you are, then, change your $days array into a bidirectional array with week days names, add day cell on the loop and an empty cell at the top. (see code comments)

```
<?php

// days of week array
$days = array( 
1 => 'Monday', 
2 => 'Tuesday', 
3 => 'Wednesday', 
4 => 'Thursday', 
5 => 'Friday', 
6 => 'Saturday', 
7 => 'Sunday' );

//Selecting all the hours from lectures
// $hours = select id, start_time from lectures;

// $timetable = select timetable.id, timetable.day, timetable.lecture_id, timetable.subject_id from timetable;



echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

echo '<td></td>'; // empty cell

foreach( $hours as $hh ) {

    echo "<td>";    
    echo $hh->start_time;
    echo "</td>";

}

echo "</tr>";

foreach( $hours as $hour ) {

    foreach( $days as $day => $day_name ) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>', $day_name, '</td>'; // day of the week

        foreach( $timetable as $tt ) {

            echo "<td>";

            if( (int)$tt->day == $day and $tt->lecture_id == $hour->id ) {
                echo $tt->subject_id;
            }

            echo "</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

If you don't want to create a bidirectional array, use PHP's function [jddayofweek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php). Here is an example:

```
<?php


//Array for days starting from 1 for monday
$days = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 );

foreach ( $days as $day ) {

    echo jddayofweek( $day - 1, 1 ), '<br>';

}

?>
```

However, for performance reasons, I do recommend that you use the bidirectional array.

Comment: This creates a table with Days entry repeated 5 times. Like 5 times monday to Sunday repeated. Also subject cells are not at their right place

Comment: well I think the html is a little out of place. Can anyone please help wih that

Comment: please help me into this